# Can the standard deviation change if the entire dataset is replicated?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Let's say I have a dataset :

`{ a, b, c, d, e }`.

I calculate the standard deviation of the set and name it `S`.

If I replicate my dataset and now use this one :
`{ a, b, c, d, e, a', b', c', d', e' }` with `a' = a`, `b' = b` and so on... which is basically :

`{ a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d, e, e }`

Will the standard deviation of this new dataset always be the same as `S`, the standard deviation of the original dataset ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Just look at the definition of standard deviation. What can you infer from that?

Comment: It should be the same because the mean and variance will be the same. Well that's what comes to mind but I'm not actually 100% sure otherwise I wouldn't ask :>

Comment: It matters whether "standard deviation" means sample standard deviation or something else.

Comment: @DavidK I think I mean sample standard deviation but I may be wrong. I'm not sure what else I could be mistaking it for (not a native english speaker).

Comment: You could be looking at the entire population of something. But sample standard deviation seems like a reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the sample standard deviation (and sample variance), then it will actually decrease a bit. That's because the additional observations make us a bit more confident that the sample mean $\hat \mu$ is close to the true mean $\mu$.

Since the sample standard deviation is a measure of the deviations from the sample mean, there is a slight bias here: the sample mean is presumably better fitted to our data than the true mean. The doubled observations increase our confidence in the accuracy of the sample mean, and therefore they decrease this bias.

Specifically, in formulas, the sample standard deviation is given by
$$
\hat\sigma = \sqrt\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \hat \mu)^2}{n-1}
$$
See that $n-1$ in the denominator? That's how we cope with the bias mentioned in the above paragraphs. As we double the observations, the sum in the numerator doubles, while the denominator is slightly more than doubled, resulting in a net decrease in sample standard deviation.

Comment: Yes that makes sense ! At first glance it looked weird to me but yes, increasing sample size does make a difference and realistically the opposite would have been weirder. Great explaination, easy to grasp for me, thanks a lot :D

Comment: The only thing I don't get is why in the variance formula we divide by `n` while here we divide by `n-1`. I missed where this transformation occured. I'll try to look up a demonstration of this formula.

Comment: @Norgannon We divide by $n$ when we know the _true_ distribution, and are calculating the _true_ variance. When we only have a sample, and we're calculating the sample variance, we divide by $n-1$.

Comment: Oh right, that's why you specified *sample* variance. That makes sense, thanks again :D